# Azure SQL Contained User. Back-end can't connect using connection string

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-sql

I followed this guide https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5242/adding-users-to-azure-sql-databases/ to create a new user for my back-end API with restricted permissions for basic security reasons but can't make the back-end connect to the server. Every time it tries to connect I'm getting

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed for user 'xxxx'.'

I'm able to log-in this new user via SSMS by setting the target database in the login window options.

The back-end can connect just fine with the default connection string supplied by the Azure Portal, witch uses the server admin login. Changing the username and password for the new user, keeping the Initial Catalog to my desired database does not work.
I would assume the back-end would be able to access it since the Initial Catalog property of the connection string is set to the database the contained user was created on. But nothing is working.

This is my connection string used on my back-end:

> Server=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=dbName;Persist
> Security Info=False;User
> ID=newUser;Password=newUserPw;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection
> Timeout=30;

I tried many guides but none worked before I found this one that seems to be very knowledgeable about creating Azure SQL users, but even so no luck so far.

This are the commands I used to create the user on the DB I need it to connect(ofc with my own values):

```
-- select your db in dropdown and create a contained user 
CREATE USER [test] 
WITH PASSWORD = 'SuperSecret!', 
DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo; 
  
-- add user to role(s) in db 
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [test]; 
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [test];
```

Anyone knows whats going on? I don't want to have to use my admin login on my back-end.

Comment: That all looks correct.

Comment: Did you grant permissions for that user to access your dbName?

Comment: Just to rule out a few scenarios, does it work with your admin login?

Comment: @VovaBilyachat the commands to create the user were executed on that dbName database. That user can access dbName via SSMS if I set the dbName on login window options. When the back-end trys to access using the conn-string, with Initial Catalog set to dbName it throws a 'login failed for user'

Comment: @KalyanChanumolu-MSFT, yes it does.

Comment: Hope you had went through this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102605/azure-sql-database-login-failed-for-user-in-application-but-works-fine-in-ssm)

Comment: Thanks for the link Niharika. The answer was not the accepted one in that question but the one below: Persist Security Info=True;
and nobody knows why. Can you guys from MS answer this? This is nowhere in the documentations. @DavidBrowne-Microsoft and Kalyan ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the straight answer is to set

> Persist Security Info=True;

in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

When username and password are included in connection string, security-sensitive information such as the password, is not returned as part of the connection if the connection is open or has ever been in an open state unless you set `Persist Security info to true`.

Reference: [Persist Security Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) , [sqlconnectionstringbuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)